# the problem with total when clicking check out button

Tags: java

I am doing a program as for ordering ice cream and the user first should choose between cone or cups (as buttons) and when he clicks the button the total shows in the Text field, and then he can proceed to choose the flavor as checkbox and the total will add whenever he add an extra flavor and so on

the problem is when i press Check out buttons it changes for another value than the grand totoal that its supposed to be

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String a = e.getActionCommand();
         double ttt;
         if(a.equals("cone")){
                total = (total +7); 
            t1.setText(Double.toString(total));

        } else if(a.equals("cup")){
                total = (total +5); 
            t1.setText(Double.toString(total));

            }
        if(RB3.isSelected()){

        total = total +7; 
            t1.setText(Double.toString(total));

        }
        if(RB2.isSelected()){

                total = (total +7); 
            t1.setText(Double.toString(total));

        }if(RB1.isSelected()){

                total = (total +7); 
            t1.setText(Double.toString(total));

        }if(CB1.isSelected()){

            total = (total +5); 
            t1.setText(Double.toString(total));

        } if(CB2.isSelected()){

            total = (total +5); 
            t1.setText(Double.toString(total));

        } if(CB3.isSelected()){

            total = (total +5); 
            t1.setText(Double.toString(total));

        }if(a.equals("Clear")){
                t1.setText(" ");
                t2.setText("");
                t3.setText("");
                RB1.setSelected(false);
                RB2.setSelected(false);
                RB3.setSelected(false);
                CB1.setSelected(false);
                CB2.setSelected(false);
                CB3.setSelected(false);
                total = 0; 

            }if(a.equals("Apply Code")){

        String c=   t2.getText(); 
            if(c.equals("DISC10")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Code applied Successfully");
                ttt=total-total*0.1;
                t3.setText(Double.toString(ttt));

            }
            else if(c.equals("")){
                t3.setText(Double.toString(total));
            }
            }
            if(a.equals("Check Out")){

                t3.setText(Double.toString(total));
```

and even when i apply the coupon code the total changes

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.   At a quick glance, it's clear that you're going to touch `total` more than once on a single action - first if action is cup or cone, and then if any of the RB radio buttons is selected, and then yet again if any of the CB buttons are selected.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand from the code you are trying to handle different steps in a single method thus calculating for each step every action.

Try and differentiate the steps on their own methods

Ex: choose ice cream type

```
void chooseIceCreamType(ActionEvent event) {
        String a = event.getActionCommand();
        if(a.equals("cone")){
            total = (total +7); 
            t1.setText(Double.toString(total));
        } else if(a.equals("cup")){
            total = (total +5); 
            t1.setText(Double.toString(total));
        }
}
```

after the user chooses the ice cream type and continues with flavors, calculate the selected flavors

```
void calculateSelectedFlavors(ActionEvent event) {
    if(RB3.isSelected()){
        total = total +7; 
        t1.setText(Double.toString(total));
    } if(RB2.isSelected()){
        total = (total +7); 
        t1.setText(Double.toString(total));
    } if(RB1.isSelected()){
        total = (total +7); 
        t1.setText(Double.toString(total));
    } if(CB1.isSelected()){
        total = (total +5); 
        t1.setText(Double.toString(total));
    } if(CB2.isSelected()){
        total = (total +5); 
        t1.setText(Double.toString(total));
    } if(CB3.isSelected()){
        total = (total +5); 
        t1.setText(Double.toString(total));
    }
}
```

and handle clear, apply code and checkout buttons on their own event methods

```
void handleOnClear(ActionEvent event) {
    t1.setText(" ");
    t2.setText("");
    t3.setText("");
    RB1.setSelected(false);
    RB2.setSelected(false);
    RB3.setSelected(false);
    CB1.setSelected(false);
    CB2.setSelected(false);
    CB3.setSelected(false);
    total = 0; 
}

void handleOnCodeApplied(ActionEvent event) {
    String c=   t2.getText(); 
    if(c.equals("DISC10")){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Code applied Successfully");
       ttt=total-total*0.1;
       t3.setText(Double.toString(ttt));
    }else if(c.equals("")){
       t3.setText(Double.toString(total));
    }
}

void checkOut(ActionEvent event) {
   t3.setText(Double.toString(total));
   //handle checkout logic
}
```

Comment: so as I understood its better to use multiple methods to handle the event, but do i have to define these methods before or do I use it immediately? i tried to apply your code and i think the action fired is not handled by the methods..

Comment: you have to specify the method that is gonna handle the event when creating the buttons and assigning those events for buttons

Comment: b1.chooseIceCreamType(this); this way you mean? sorry for having many questions but its my first time to know that events can be handled my multiple methods!

Comment: b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        chooseIceCreamType(e);
   }
});

Comment: unfortunately i could find a way to understand it and implement it and it didn't work with me  but thanks for the help so far..